# Angular CLI ng serve with --base-href - I do not understand its behavior

Tags: angular

I am new in Angular CLI.
I am writing an new app, and in the `index.html` I insert `base href`, 
for example - `<base href="/a/">`.

When I use`ng serve` and go to `localhost:4200/a` (or even `localhost:4200`) I see a white screen, but when I use `ng serve --base-href /a/` I see my app in `localhost:4200`, in `localhost:4200/a`, and actually in every url that starts with `localhost:4200` for example `localhost:4200/aaaaaaa`.

I do not understand this behavior.

From the documentation I understood that this flag just change the `base href` in `index html`, but I already have this base href in my `index.html` so why my app doesn't work just with `ng serve` in `localhost:4200/a`?

And why when I use `ng serve --base-href /a/` it is not working ONLY at `localhost:4200/a`? what do I miss? 
I am really confused.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your package.json code?

Comment: Are you missing the quotes? `--base-href "/a/"`

Comment: I hava quotes, and I hava the latest angular version, I used "ng new app" two days ago.

Answer (score 15):

These options have changed and current version of angular (`13.3.9`) and cli (`13.3.6`) does not support `--base-href` for [`ng serve`](https://angular.io/cli/serve#options) anymore.

To serve your site under `/a` path you should use `ng serve --serve-path a` and to tell browser to use `/a/` as a base path you need to update this setting in angular.json file:

- add `"baseHref": "/a/"` property to `architect` > `build` > `options` object.

The issue with being able to access your app under `/a`, `/aaaaaaa` etc. could have been related to your router configuration.

If your router is configured to resolve any route starting with `/a` to a component/module, then this is expected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

What the --base-href option does is change the  value in index.html. This in turn defines the base URI for the document and is used for all relative URL within the document. The default base URI is the location of the document (index.html in this case).

Note also that the base href can technically be set to an absolute URL as well.

There is also the --deploy-url option, which webpack uses to adjust all requests for assets it manages.

You generally use this to reverse proxy your application.